# Reference for a paper

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory

This paper of Hasse deals with finding prime $q$ such that $ord_qp$ is even for some (fixed) prime $p$. Can some one suggest an online copy of it ? Or any survey in which its main ideas are highlighted.

H. Hasse, Über die Dichte der Primzahlen p, für die eine vorgegebene ganzrationale
Zahl $a \neq 0$ von gerader bzw.ungerader Ordnung mod. p ist, Math. Ann. 166
(1966), 19–23.

Comment: As it is an article written before 1997, you have an open access to it : see indication at the bottom of (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematische_Annalen)

Answer (score 1):

Among the first things which are quite natural to try, is to search [in Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Hasse+Dichte+der+Primzahlen). For scientific papers [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=Hasse+Dichte+der+Primzahlen) might be sometimes more suitable. Notice that in Google Scholar you can often see link called all versions - if there are several versions available on line. In this specific case you get [this](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=9873927886986624281&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5).

Either way, you find this [eudml link](https://eudml.org/doc/161322) from which you can get to freely available version of the paper [at GDZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_for_Retrospective_Digitization). (You can either read the paper online or download pdf.

You can find several posts containing some advice on how and where to search for papers, for example, answers to this post: [Finding a paper](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40762/finding-a-paper).